# I've created a function to create a worksheets based on the workbook provided as input, but I get error 428 each time I try to call it:

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Licious()

Dim Files As Variant
Dim WkBk As Workbook
Dim WkSh, WkSh2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Files = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select the bills for Licious", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*), *.xls", MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(Files) Then

 For i = 1 To UBound(Files)

  Set WkBk = Workbooks.Open(Files(i))

   For Each WkSh In WkBk.Worksheets

    If WkSh.Name <> "Table 10" Then: WkSh.Delete
   Next WkSh
      
   Set WkSh2 = Items_Ordered (WkBk)      

   WkSh2.Activate

 Next i

End If
    
End Sub



Function Items_Ordered(WkBk As Workbook) As Worksheet

Dim Cell, Delivery_Charge, Item_Range As Range
Dim Item_Count, Counter, Row_Id, Total_Qty As Integer

Total_Qty = WkBk.Worksheets("Table 10").Range("B2:B" & Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row)

WkBk.Worksheets.Add After:="Table 10"

'Sets the table structre for the 'Items Ordered' worksheet:
With ActiveSheet
 .Name = "Items Ordered"

 .Range("A1") = "Date"

 .Range("B1") = "Narration"

 .Range("C1") = "Chq./Ref.No."

 .Range("D1") = "Value Dt"

 .Range("E1") = "Withdrawal Amt."

 .Range("F1") = "Deposit Amt."

 .Range("G1") = "Closing Balance"

 .Range("H1") = "Expense Line"

 .Range("I1") = "Comments"

 .Columns("A:H").ColumnWidth = 18.33
End With

'Summary Prep:

'1. Ascerating the range of cells in "Table 10" worksheet that contains the names of the items to be added to the "Items Ordered" worksheet:

Set Delivery_Charge = WkBk.Worksheets("Table 10").Range("A:A").Find(What:="Delivery Charge", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Set Item_Range = WkBk.Worksheets("Table 10").Range("A2:A" & Delivery_Charge.Row - 1)

'2. Transfer the items to the "Items Ordered" worksheet:

If WkBk.Worksheets("Items Ordered").Range("H2") = "" Then

 For Each Cell In Item_Range

   Item_Count = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

   For Counter = 1 To Item_Count

     Row_Id = WkBk.Worksheets("Items Ordered").Range("H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Row + 1

     WkBk.Worksheets("Items Ordered").Range("A" & Row_Id) = CDate(VBA.Replace(WkBk.Name, ".xlsx", ""))

      WkBk.Worksheets("Items Ordered").Range("H" & Row_Id) = Cell.Value

      WkBk.Worksheets("Items Ordered").Range("E" & Row_Id) = -(Cell.Offset(0, 3) / Item_Count)

   Next Counter
 Next Cell
End If

Set Items_Ordered(WkBk) = WkBk.Worksheets("Items Ordered")

End Function
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: The error pops up as soon as I call it in my sub-procedure: Items_Ordered(WkBk)

Comment: `Items_Ordered` is a function, which returns a worksheet - yet you're calling it as if it's a `Sub`..?

Comment: The idea was to pass the workbook as an argument, and the function creates the required worksheet in the said workbook and returns it.

Comment: Returns it to what? You'd need to call it, referenced. e.g. `Set returned_worksheet=Items_Ordered(WkBk)`, or if you're not going to actually use the returned reference, make it a `Sub`.

Comment: So I added another variable - WkSh2. Now, WkSh2 - Items_Ordered(WkBk). This time the function is called, but I get an error #1004 on line 36 - WkBk.Worksheets.Add After:="Table 10" i.e. its unable to run the add method for the worksheet. Any idea why?

Comment: `WkBk.Worksheets.Add After:=WkBk.Worksheets("Table 10")`